# Debug stuck at _kill process

Tags: c++, stm32

I'm working on the STM32 platform trying to use an API I haven't gotten working on this platform yet. I have used it use JUCE on Windows with no issues. They API is HVCC (https://github.com/enzienaudio/hvcc/blob/master/docs/10.c.md). When calling the hv_processInline function it will run once then I get stuck in the _kill process in syscalls.c . What are some troubleshooting steps I can take to see how I end up in this function?

When I comment out the hv_processInline function my I2S callback continues to run. When the hv_processInline function is used I see that it runs once by setting a breakpoint in the function and then after that when I pause I'm always in the _kill function.

```
int Heavy_sin440::process(float **inputBuffers, float **outputBuffers, int n) {
  while (hLp_hasData(&inQueue)) {
    hv_uint32_t numBytes = 0;
    ReceiverMessagePair *p = reinterpret_cast<ReceiverMessagePair *>(hLp_getReadBuffer(&inQueue, &numBytes));
    hv_assert(numBytes >= sizeof(ReceiverMessagePair));
    scheduleMessageForReceiver(p->receiverHash, &p->msg);
    hLp_consume(&inQueue);
  }
  const int n4 = n & ~HV_N_SIMD_MASK; // ensure that the block size is a multiple of HV_N_SIMD

  // temporary signal vars
  hv_bufferf_t Bf0, Bf1;

  // input and output vars
  hv_bufferf_t O0, O1;

  // declare and init the zero buffer
  hv_bufferf_t ZERO; __hv_zero_f(VOf(ZERO));

  hv_uint32_t nextBlock = blockStartTimestamp;
  for (int n = 0; n < n4; n += HV_N_SIMD) {

    // process all of the messages for this block
    nextBlock += HV_N_SIMD;
    while (mq_hasMessageBefore(&mq, nextBlock)) {
      MessageNode *const node = mq_peek(&mq);
      node->sendMessage(this, node->let, node->m);
      mq_pop(&mq);
    }



    // zero output buffers
    __hv_zero_f(VOf(O0));
    __hv_zero_f(VOf(O1));

    // process all signal functions
    __hv_phasor_k_f(&sPhasor_f2NcS0wF, VOf(Bf0));
    __hv_biquad_k_f(&sBiquad_k_R2PEvfbY, VIf(Bf0), VOf(Bf0));
    __hv_var_k_f(VOf(Bf1), 4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f);
    __hv_mul_f(VIf(Bf0), VIf(Bf1), VOf(Bf1));
    __hv_add_f(VIf(Bf1), VIf(O1), VOf(O1));
    __hv_add_f(VIf(Bf1), VIf(O0), VOf(O0));

    // save output vars to output buffer
    __hv_store_f(outputBuffers[0]+n, VIf(O0));
    __hv_store_f(outputBuffers[1]+n, VIf(O1));
  }

  blockStartTimestamp = nextBlock;

  return n4; // return the number of frames processed
}

int Heavy_sin440::processInline(float *inputBuffers, float *outputBuffers, int n4) {
  hv_assert(!(n4 & HV_N_SIMD_MASK)); // ensure that n4 is a multiple of HV_N_SIMD

  // define the heavy input buffer for 0 channel(s)
  float **const bIn = NULL;

  // define the heavy output buffer for 2 channel(s)
  float **const bOut = reinterpret_cast<float **>(hv_alloca(2*sizeof(float *)));
  bOut[0] = outputBuffers+(0*n4);
  bOut[1] = outputBuffers+(1*n4);

  int n = process(bIn, bOut, n4);
  return n;
}

int Heavy_sin440::processInlineInterleaved(float *inputBuffers, float *outputBuffers, int n4) {
  hv_assert(n4 & ~HV_N_SIMD_MASK); // ensure that n4 is a multiple of HV_N_SIMD

  // define the heavy input buffer for 0 channel(s), uninterleave
  float *const bIn = NULL;

  // define the heavy output buffer for 2 channel(s)
  float *const bOut = reinterpret_cast<float *>(hv_alloca(2*n4*sizeof(float)));

  int n = processInline(bIn, bOut, n4);

  // interleave the heavy output into the output buffer
  #if HV_SIMD_AVX
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < n4; j += 8, i += 16) {
    __m256 x = _mm256_load_ps(bOut+j);    // LLLLLLLL
    __m256 y = _mm256_load_ps(bOut+n4+j); // RRRRRRRR
    __m256 a = _mm256_unpacklo_ps(x, y);  // LRLRLRLR
    __m256 b = _mm256_unpackhi_ps(x, y);  // LRLRLRLR
    _mm256_store_ps(outputBuffers+i, a);
    _mm256_store_ps(outputBuffers+8+i, b);
  }
  #elif HV_SIMD_SSE
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < n4; j += 4, i += 8) {
    __m128 x = _mm_load_ps(bOut+j);    // LLLL
    __m128 y = _mm_load_ps(bOut+n4+j); // RRRR
    __m128 a = _mm_unpacklo_ps(x, y);  // LRLR
    __m128 b = _mm_unpackhi_ps(x, y);  // LRLR
    _mm_store_ps(outputBuffers+i, a);
    _mm_store_ps(outputBuffers+4+i, b);
  }
  #elif HV_SIMD_NEON
  // https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2012/03/13/coding-for-neon--part-5-rearranging-vectors
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < n4; j += 4, i += 8) {
    float32x4_t x = vld1q_f32(bOut+j);
    float32x4_t y = vld1q_f32(bOut+n4+j);
    float32x4x2_t z = {x, y};
    vst2q_f32(outputBuffers+i, z); // interleave and store
  }
  #else // HV_SIMD_NONE
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n4; ++j) {
      outputBuffers[i+2*j] = bOut[i*n4+j];
    }
  }
  #endif

  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I believe the issue here is I wasn't using the correct generator flags when running the hvcc python script. I guess by default it is setup to export a VST but I needed to use the "-g c" flag and now everything is working properly.